# Codename One - Remove borders between multiple commands

Tags: codenameone

I want to add multiple commands to the Toolbar but when I do I get these black borders around each

[image]

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Codename One - Style border of overflow menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049869/codename-one-style-border-of-overflow-menu/53057424) so the answer is almost identical:

Open the TitleCommand UIID. Go to the Border style and click "Override". Click the ... button. Pick empty border.

Comment: I did it like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ZpIi52H.png) but as you can see I still have the borders.

Comment: Did you do this for selected/unselected & pressed?

Comment: Yes, still the same black borders.

Comment: By the way I've added them with `addCommandToRightBar` if that changes anything.

Comment: Select margin and select 0, this might be margin showing the background color of the `Toolbar` itself.