# Codename One - Style border of overflow menu

Tags: codenameone

I'm try to style the border of the overflow menu. Right now it looks like this.

[image]

I want to give it a small black border instead of the blue it is now. I've tried the `Menu` in the Designer but no luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `TitleCommand` UIID. Go to the Border style and click "Override". Click the `...` button. Pick line border and uncheck the "Theme Colors". Select the color you want for the border and its thickness.

Comment: Tried that but I think we're talking about different things. Now the three dots have a black border but the overflow menu itself with the commands still has the blue border. See [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/CQMRh3d.png)

Comment: Try styling the `Menu` UIID

Comment: The outside is now white but I still have the blue bar. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/6jC1pIy.png)

Comment: Try styling `CommandList`. FYI you can launch Component Inspector in the simulator and traverse the hierarchy to try and find the applicable UIID

Comment: [Not much there](https://i.imgur.com/kZ3xDkx.png) `CommandList` wasn't the solution either. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ekOODdQ.png)

Comment: Hmm I've changed all of the theme UIID's to black or white borders and that seems to have fixed it. it seems it was the `CommandList`. Thanks for the help again!